# steps_per_epoch keras with theano

Tags: python, keras, theano

I have the error below when I execute my code. I am using keras 2.2.5 and theano 1.0.4.

> ValueError: steps_per_epoch=None is only valid for a generator based on the keras.utils.Sequence class. Please specify steps_per_epoch or use the keras.utils.Sequence class.

Here is my code:

```
model.fit_generator( train_gen, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch=int(len(train[0]) / batch_size), epochs=MAX_EPOCHS, validation_data=dev_gen, validation_steps=int(len(dev[0]) / batch_size), callbacks=[checkpointer, reduce_lr, stopping])
```

Comment: Please tell us more: What are you trying to do? When do you get this error? Also give a simple reproducible example of your code.

Comment: The message is totally clear. Your generator is not a `keras.utils.Sequence`, thus, you need to pass `steps_per_epoch` (how many batches to get from the generator per epoch) to the `fit_generator` method.

Comment: thank you for the reply. below the code model.fit_generator(
            train_gen,
            steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch=int(len(train[0]) / batch_size),
            epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
            validation_data=dev_gen,
            validation_steps=int(len(dev[0]) / batch_size),
            callbacks=[checkpointer, reduce_lr, stopping])
'